# Error while compiling hello world project for android in Intellij under ubuntu

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

Could you please help me with my struggle to start/build my first hello world application for android? I am using ubuntu as my operating system. I downloaded android sdk as well as Intellij. I added libraries. I handled error connected to missing android.app by mentioned previously libraries. Unfortunately I met another issue with the following message:

> Information:Compilation completed with 33 errors and 0 warnings in 9
>   sec Information:33 errors Information:0 warnings  trouble processing
>   "javax/crypto/ExemptionMechanismSpi.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) 
>   when not building a core library.  This is often due to inadvertently
>   including a core library file  in your application's project, when
>   using an IDE (such as  Eclipse). If you are sure you're not
>   intentionally defining a  core class, then this is the most likely
>   explanation of what's  going on.  However, you might actually be
>   trying to define a class in a core  namespace, the source of which you
>   may have taken, for example,  from a non-Android virtual machine
>   project. This will most  assuredly not work. At a minimum, it
>   jeopardizes the  compatibility of your app with future versions of the
>   platform.   It is also often of questionable legality.  If you really
>   intend to build a core library -- which is only  appropriate as part
>   of creating a full virtual machine  distribution, as opposed to
>   compiling an application -- then use  the "--core-library" option to
>   suppress this error message.   If you go ahead and use
>   "--core-library" but are in fact  building an application, then be
>   forewarned that your application  will still fail to build or run, at
>   some point. Please be  prepared for angry customers who find, for
>   example, that your  application ceases to function once they upgrade
>   their operating  system. You will be to blame for this problem.  If
>   you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a  core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to  repackage
>   that code.  That is, move the classes in question into  your own
>   package namespace. This means that they will never be in  conflict
>   with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help  you in this
>   endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then  that is an
>   indication that the path you are on will ultimately  lead to pain,
>   suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>
> 1 error; aborting

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please include the *complete* message.

Comment: Hello. I've just added full message.

Comment: I have reformatted the message so it's readable. It pretty much explains in detail what the problem is. Are you defining any classes in the `java` or `javax` namespace? That is, do you have something like `package java;` at the top of one of your source files?

Comment: not really, I assume i should not add one? However as I noticed in exaples on the web it was not needed or at least I did not find any case with java package added/

Comment: Ah, no. You should be writing code that compiles into your *own* namespace, not the system `java` namespace. But for some reason, the Android build thinks you are. If you're still getting this error and you don't know why, I would suggest starting over with the "hello world" tutorial in a fresh project, following directions carefully.

Comment: thank you, i will follow you advice

Comment: It appears to tell you the troublesome class: `javax/crypto/ExemptionMechanismSpi.class` Are you including the crypto libs from the Java SDK, either directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to remove android.jar from your build path (Project Structure> Libraries> android library> detach android.jar).